# Get only time from Datetime field

Tags: visualforce

I want to display only `time` value in `apex:outputText`.Is there any format to display only time.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a `apex:param` for that:

```
   <apex:outputText value="The formatted time right now is: 
         {0,date,HH:mm:ss}">
       <apex:param value="{!NOW()}" />
   </apex:outputText>
```

Check this doc: [apex:outputText](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm)

Comment: thanks for the response.i tried that before i am getting "The value attribute on <apex:outputText> is not in a valid format. It must be a positive number, and of type Number, Date, Time, or Choice" error.

Comment: The above code works if we use NOW() function,if i use DateTime field of Custom object its showing error.

Comment: @NullReferenceException Your comment is not correct. It work with a normal custom DateTime field very well, just checked in my dev org.

Comment: I am getting the error "The value attribute on <apex:outputText> is not in a valid format. It must be a positive number, and of type Number, Date, Time, or Choice". This is my code <apex:column headerValue="Start Time">
                                             <apex:outputText value="{0,date,HH:mm:ss}">                                                 <apex:param value="{!item.StartTime__c}"/>                                                 </apex:outputText>
</apex:column>

Comment: @NullReferenceException There is something wrong with your `StartTime__c` value. Better check it without using above solution firstly. And the field should be of type `DateTime` of cource, not a Text or something else.

Comment: I am just saving datetime value to StartTime__c field.Without formatting it shows date and time correctly, but when accessing time value only its showing error.